# Possibility of making an Overlay window parent of root window

Tags: window, x11, cairo, xlib, xorg

I wanted to know if it is possible to draw a window (like overlay window) or a shape (using cairo) such that, that window is the parent of root window.

It seems illogical to think like this, as root window itself means the root of all windows; but still I am curious if this is possible. If yes then what is the method for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want this window to be the parent of the root window? Like, which "problem" cares about the parent-child relationship between windows and would be solved by having a parent of the root window?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The root window is the root of the window hierarchy.